# Check if all dep packages dependencies are satisfied

Tags: package-management

I sometimes install .deb files that have a "Provides" field. From what I understand, if e.g. a package called "expack" is listed here then if another .deb file depends on expack it will not need to install it (if I do apt-get). But if I do `apt-cache show expack` then it will not show that it's installed. So how do I check that the 'expack' dependency is installed (without using a specific package that depends on 'expack', just using only the argument 'expack') ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the answer:

```
apt-cache showpkg expack
```

Source: Commrent below by [Xu-Wang](https://askubuntu.com/users/230302/xu-wang)

Also, the whereis command works in most cases to show these packages and their path or location as well.

```
whereis expack
```

here's the output:

```
expack: /usr/games/expack /usr/share/man/man1/expack.1.gz
```

This shows that expack *is* installed and the location is "/usr/games/expack" .

Also, packages that are typically provided by other packages in virtual packages will typically show using the apt-cache search command

```
apt-cache search expack
```

here's the output

```
exult-studio - tools for editing and viewing exult games
```

So, exult-studio provides expack and satisfies the dependency expack according to http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html (see 7.5 virtual packages)

where expack = bar and exult-studio = bar-plus.

To see a list of a packages dependencies and to also see if the dependencies are already installed, use the application `apt-rdepends`

```
sudo apt-get apt-rdepends
```

To list dependencies and status of all dependencies as well use `apt-rdepends -p`

```
apt-rdepends -p packagename
```

Comment: that would show if the `expack` is installed. It would not show if the `expack` dependency is satisfied. It is a different thing. For more information on "provides", see http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html

Comment: @XuWang I'm sorry, I misunderstood and the answer has been updated. Please let me know if that's not what you are looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your effort (+1). I finally found what I was looking for. If I do "apt-cache showpkg expack", if expack is known to apt then it will list "reverse provides". That's what I'm interested in. Can you add that to your answer?